# CMS Made Simple Link

Tags: content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I would like to set up links though my site to make it easier to type long urls to external sites, How would I set up CMS Made Simple to link from one internal URL to a exteral one IE mydomain.com/fb to facebook.com/mycompany/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your (V1.x) admin area, try:

Content > Pages > Add new content

Content type: Redirecting link

Options tab:

- Page alias: "fb"
- If you don't want it to show in menu untick "Show in menu"

Main tab:

- Fill in title and menu
- In URL: "facebook.com/mycompany/"

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks that was it

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to an external URL (or even content within your domain that is not managed by CMSMS), you can use the Content Type "Redirecting Link".

Since [maidbloke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733402/maidbloke) already [covered CMSMS 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623984/514479), I'll cover CMSMS 2.x.

## Creating the Redirecting Link

1. Start at the CMSMS admin area's "Home" page (the default page loaded in the admin area).
2. Under the "Content" item, click the "Content Manager" subitem.  You could also, instead, open the "Content" menu on the left by clicking "Content" in the left hand menu, and then click the "Content Manager" subitem.
3. Click "Add New Content" in the upper left of the Content Manager area.
4. In the "Main" tab, change the Content Type to "Redirecting Link".
5. Fill in the "Title" field.
6. Fill in the "URL" field (something like "https://www.facebook.com/mycompany" without quotes).
7. Click on the "Navigation" tab.
8. Fill in the "Menu Text" field.
9. If you don't want the link to show in your menus, uncheck the "Show in Menu" option.
10. If you set the "Title" to something other than "fb"...

    1. Click on the "Options" tab.
    2. Fill in the "Alias" field with "fb".
11. At the top of this page, click the "Submit" button to save your new content.

Now the redirecting link is set up!  Next, we'll cover how to use it.

## Using the Redirecting Link

There are a few ways you can use it.

### Without MicroTiny

If you're not using MicroTiny or some other WYSIWYG editor:

A. You can use raw HTML:

```
<a href="fb">Our Facebook Page</a>
<a href="//example.com/fb">Our Facebook Page</a>
<a href="http://example.com/fb">Our Facebook Page</a>
<a href="https://example.com/fb">Our Facebook Page</a>
```

B. You can use the cms_selflink tag:

```
{cms_selflink page="fb" text="Our Facebook Page"}
```

You can still use this method from within MicroTiny as well.

### With MicroTiny

If you're using MicroTiny:

C. You can insert a CMSMS page link:

1. Click the "Insert" menu.
2. Click "Link to CMSMS Page".
3. Fill out the "Enter Page title" field with the value you used when you created the Redirecting Link (Creating the Redirecting Link, Step 5).
4. Fill out the "Text to display" field.
5. Click the "Ok" button.

There is also a button in MicroTiny toolbar that can be used to replace steps 1 and 2.

D. You can insert a regular link:

1. Click the "Insert" menu.
2. Click "Insert/edit link".
3. Fill in the "Url" field, probably with one of the URLs shown in option A.
4. Fill in the "Text to display" field.
5. Fill in the "Title" field.
6. Click the "Ok" button.

There is also a button in MicroTiny toolbar that can be used to replace steps 1 and 2.  You could also press the Control and K keys together to insert a regular link.